# What is the difference between NAT and PAT?

Tags: ipv4

PAT is also called overloading NAT. I don't understand why we need to use PAT? NAT alone is handling IPv4 addresses then why it is required to translate port also?Today's home wifi router use both NAT and PAT simultaneously which is also called NPAT. Your network will still work without PAT also then why PAT is used?

NAT: Network Address Translation; PAT: Port Address Translation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-NAT-and-PAT says: *"NAPT (Network Address and Port Translation) is the more descriptive name for PAT, but it is harder to say.  **Most devices that claim to do NAT are really doing NAPT, including just about every home router on the market.**"*

Comment: (In other words,  if your WiFi router used true NAT, it would only support one private IP address ... assuming that your ISP / telco assigns you one public IP.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Network Address Translation* (**NAT**) and *Port Address Translation* (**PAT**) both `map` **IP** addresses on an internal network to **IP** addresses on an external network.  Which method of address translation you use depends on the types of networks that you are translating and the number of available **IP** addresses that you have.

Please [see.](http://blog.boson.com/bid/53313/NAT-and-PAT-What-s-the-Difference)